# How can I upsert the document using 'filter'?

Tags: regex, mongodb, go

This updates the existing document (if `_id` with matching pattern `idPattern` does exist):

```
customerName := "somename"
idPattern := "^" + customerName
filter := bson.M{"_id": primitive.Regex{Pattern: idPattern}}
update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "a":        "value1",
        "b":        "value2",
    }}

opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)
result, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update, opts)
```

---

If the document does not exist with `filter := bson.M{"_id": idPattern}`, then,

How can I insert a new document by creating a new id (`"_id" : customerName + "_" + uuid.New().String()`)? Without using `collection.Find()`...

Can `filter` help perform insert document using the same `collection.UpdateOne()` instruction (shown above)?

Comment: Given you perform update when the prefix exists, and insert if not, the prefix should be the sole ID, and you should use equality match. Then your problem goes away.

Comment: @icza ###1) Prefix should be the sole ID.. ok, I will use `filter := bson.M{"_id": customerName}` and it is safe in our scenario. customerName is not coming from user.  ###2) When you say, "you should use equality match", do you mean, `filter := bson.M{"_id":  bson.M{"eq": customerName}}` works, but, `filter := bson.M{"_id":   customerName}` does not work?

Comment: By using equality match I mean not regexp. `filter := bson.M{"_id": customerName}` is fine.